# HttpWebRequest error 500 (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: httpwebrequest

I am trying to get content of http://validator.w3.org/mobile/check?docAddr=www.facebook.com in C#. This is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = "A .NET Web Crawler";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The code works correctly with other pages, but with http://validator.w3.org/mobile/check?docAddr=www.facebook.com and a different `docAddr` it's giving me a 500 error. I check with Fiddler and the error is:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 03 Jun 2011 22:18:36 GMT
Server: Jigsaw/2.2.6
Content-Length: 59
Content-Type: text/html
Via: 1.1 validator.w3.org
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close

Servlet has thrown exception:java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: try changing your user agent to the one sent by IE or Firefox?

Comment: The problem is on the jigsaw server. You can download it and run it on a port on your machine. Then point your C# client to it, and see if it reproes? Maybe you might be able to get a stack trace